# How to change the variable length in Progress?

Tags: variables, runtime, progress-4gl, cname, openedge

I'm pretty new to progress and I want to ask a question.

How do I change variable (string) length in runtime?

```
ex.
define variable cname as char.
define variable clen as int.

cname= "".
DO cnts = 1 TO 5.
    IF prc[cnts] <> "" THEN DO:
        clen = clen + LENGTH(prc[cnts]).
        cname = cname + prc[cnts].
    END.
END.
```

Put cname format '???' at 1. /*here change variable length*/

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

If the PUT statement is what you want to change, then

```
PUT UNFORMATTED cname.
```

will write the entire string out without having to worry about the length of the FORMAT phrase.

If you need something formatted, then

```
PUT UNFORMATTED STRING(cname, fill("X", clen)).
```

will do what you want. Look up the "STRING()" function in the ABL Ref docs.

Comment: Then marking this as an answer would be the appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In Progress 4GL **all** data is variable length.

This is one of the big differences between Progress and lots of other development environments.  (And in my opinion a big advantage.)

Each datatype has a **default format**, which you can override, but that is only for display purposes.

Display format has no bearing on storage.

You can declare a field with a  display format of 3 characters:

```
define variable x as character no-undo format "x(3)".
```

And then stuff 60 characters into the field.  Progress will not complain.

```
x = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890".
```

It is extremely common for 4gl application code to over-stuff variables and fields.

(If you then use SQL-92 to access the data you will hear much whining and gnashing of teeth from your SQL client.  This is easily fixable with the "dbtool" utility.)

You change the display format when you define something:

```
define variable x as character no-undo format "x(30)".
```

or when you use it:

```
put x format "x(15)".
```

or

```
display x format "x(43)".
```

(And in many other ways -- these are just a couple of easy examples.)

Regardless of the display format the length() function will report the actual length of the data.